# Send complex types with Angular Resource to ServiceStack

Tags: angularjs, json, servicestack, deserialization, angular-resource

So I want to send some complex types with Angular Resource to my ServiceStack backend. In the frontend it looks like this:

```
MyResource.get({
    Data: { countries: ["DE","CH","AT"] }
    SomeMoreParams: "hi"
});
```

Here's my DTO:

```
[Route("/my-resource","GET")]
public class MyResource
{
    public OwnType Data { get; set; }
    public string SomeMoreData { get; set; }
}

public class OwnType
{
    public List<string> Countries { get; set; }
}
```

But it's not deserialized correctly by ServiceStack. If I send the data in a post request it works correctly. I already found out that ServiceStack uses JSV format for this case. Is there a possibility to get this working or do I have to use post or write my own Deserializer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not formal structure for sending complex types via the QueryString so we recommend keeping your Request DTO's flat so they can be easily accessed. So I would move Countries to a first-level property in your Request DTO:

```
[Route("/my-resource","GET")]
public class MyResource
{
    public List<string> Countries { get; set; }
    public string SomeMoreData { get; set; }
}
```

Which you should now be able to access with:

```
MyResource.get({
    countries: "DE,CH,AT"
    SomeMoreParams: "hi"
});
```

If you want to keep the complex type on your Request DTO than the easiest way to [send a complex type Request is to use POST](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22624568/85785).